# is order entity is EAV in magento 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, eav

i need to add to fields to the order entity, so that i can store custom datum in two fields, is it possible to add attribute to the **order entity**, because i can't get **eav tables for the order entity**,

if order entity is not EAV , then how to add custom fields to order,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sales tables are flat tables. You could add new fields via installer script to the sales_flat_order tables. Like:

```
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales_flat_order'), 'new_attribute', 'int');
$installer->getConnection()->addColumn($installer->getTable('sales_flat_order_grid'), 'new_attribute', 'int');

$installer->endSetup();
```

Comment: ,how to store the values to the fields , i'm creating order programatically , i'm creating order using quote and service objects

Comment: I'm not sure how you create these orders. Via API? Not sure if this would work for you but one option would be to create an observer which is listening to an event like 'sales_order_place_after' and add the logic there. Like

public function salesOrderPlaceAfter($observer) {
 $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
 ...
 $order->setData('new_field', $valueOfTheNewField);

 $order->save();
}